# Vernemq port 1883 with haproxy-ingress and also SSL termination

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, haproxy-ingress, mqtt-vernemq

I'm trying to deploy vernemq on kubernetes and want to access it with subdomain with ssl but ssl should be terminated before request go to vernemq on port 1883.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? It's possible to have SSL termination e.g. wigh nginx-ingress controller. Did you look at this section in its docs https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/tls-termination/ ?

Comment: Actually i know about that it work fine with http but i want that thing with tcp

Answer (score 2):

create file `haproxy-ingress-values.yaml` with following content

```
controller:
  tcp:
    "1883": "default/vernemq:1883:::default/mqtt-tls"
```

`default/vernemq:1883` is service of `vernemq` with port 1883 and `default/mqtt-tls` is tls secret for mqtt which you want terminate.

then use the following command to upgrade your `haproxy-ingress`

```
helm upgrade haproxy-ingress haproxy-ingress/haproxy-ingress --create-namespace --namespace ingress-controller --version 0.13.4 -f haproxy-ingress-values.yaml
```

just replace `upgrade` with `install` if fresh installing haproxy-ingress.

Then at last deploy the following ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vernemq-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
    ingress.kubernetes.io/tcp-service-port: "1883"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: vernemq
                port:
                  number: 1883
```