# How terminate ssl over tcp on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, traefik-ingress, haproxy-ingress

I want to deploy mqtt broker with tcp port 1883 and terminate ssl out of broker.

I know how to open tcp port with `haproxy-ingress` and `nginx-ingress` but don't know how I can use ssl terminate with it.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488472/vernemq-port-1883-with-haproxy-ingress-and-also-ssl-termination/69508953#69508953

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue and there is the information about [designing the TCP LB with our CRDs, and this will include SSL termination](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/831#issuecomment-578206759) by Nginx. Unfortunately, it was not released yet, but there is an useful workarounds described [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/831#issuecomment-635594300). Please try these solutions and if there doesn't work, please follow this thread in [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/831) and wait for any update of that upcoming release (someday).